# Processes are starting without GUI from WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, process, process.start

I need to start processes from WCF service (self-hosted). I've done it using Process.Start() method. And processes are starting without GUI, they are only visible in task manager. I've tried to invoke Process.Start method with any StartInfo parameters, but I have no result. Is there any way to start processes the same way as manually to make it visible?

**UPDATE:**
I tried to enable interaction with the desktop and I can see my application GUI but only after clicking 'Read message' (system window) manually. How can I automate it?

Comment: Maybe your new process is inheriting some of its rights from the parent process.What credentials do you have the service running under? The *Local System* account has an option that enables interaction with the desktop, but you should be runniong as something way lower than that.

Comment: I've tried to run service under different credentials. Nothing changes. I also tried to enable interaction with the desktop and I can see my application GUI only after I click 'Read message' manually. How can I automate it?

Comment: I doubt you can automate it - unfettered access from a service to the desktop was prevented from about WinXP onwards. Technically it's a bad design and you should avoid it for a variety of reasons. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So I am working on some kind of the software updater - need to update and restart files/processes on many computers from one in the 'almost' local network. I guess bad design is if some processes will not work as expected (without GUI). In my case target computers have WinXP (thanks God!). @slugster Could you please post any links with these changes about access from service to the desktop from WinXP. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Cool - I understand what you are trying to do. It's bad design to try and start **UI apps** from a service - ask yourself: who is going to interact with it? How will you open it on their console? However you can still start normal non-UI processes, so there is still potential for you to follow that path.